# Sorting an array of strings using values alphabetically and considering the cases of values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am sorting an array using values alphabetically, the array is as below:

```
Array ( 
[0] => test This 
[1] => This test 
[2] => again this test 
[3] => test again this 
[4] => this test again 
[5] => Dallas University Texas 
[6] => Texas Dallas University 
[7] => University Texas Dallas 
[8] => dallas University Texas 
[9] => Texas dallas University 
[10] => University Texas dallas 
[11] => Johnson Johnson 
[12] => Johnson Johnson
)
```

the expected output when i sort should be as below:

```
again this test  
dallas University Texas  
Dallas University Texas  
Johnson Johnson  
test again this  
test This   
this test again   
Texas dallas University   
Texas Dallas University   
This test   
University Texas dallas   
University Texas Dallas
```

my code is below:
the comparator

```
function compareValues($a,$b) {
  if ($a == $b) {
    return 0;
  }
  return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
function transform($input){
  return usort($input,array($input,"compareValues"));
}
print_r($transform($input));
```

My current output cannot alphabetize the all values and is not case sensitive, it can only produce partially ordered array. It should be the comparator function that has some fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort the array. i have the following class with methods that constitute algorithm:

```
class Alphabetizer extends AbstComposite{

    private $input = array();
    private $output = array();
function Alphabetizer( $input){
    $this->input = $input;
    $this->transform();
    $this->output();
}
    static function checkcase($string) {

        if( preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $string)){
            return 1;
        }elseif(preg_match('/[a-z]/', $string)){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return "stupid";
        }
    }
  static    function caseorder($a,$b){
       $a = preg_replace('/\s+/','',trim($a));
        $b = preg_replace('/\s+/','',trim($b));
        //checking the case ordering of words
        $length= (count($a) < count($b)) ?  count($a) :count($b);
        for($i=0;$i<=$length;$i++){
                if(strcasecmp($a[$i],$b[$i] == 0)){
                    if((Alphabetizer::checkcase($a[$i]) ==0) && Alphabetizer::checkcase($b[$i]) ==1){
                        return -1;
                    }elseif(Alphabetizer::checkcase($a[$i]==1) && Alphabetizer::checkcase($b[$i] ==0)){
                        return +1;
                    }else{
                        return 0;
                    }
                }return 0;



        }
    }
    //works well for alphabetical ordering of sentences
   static  function  letterorder($a,$b){
        $a = preg_replace('/\s+/','',trim($a));
        $b = preg_replace('/\s+/','',trim($b));
        $length= (count($a) < count($b)) ?  count($a) :count($b);
        for($i=0;$i<=$length;$i++){
            if(strtolower($a[$i]) < strtolower($b[$i])){
                return -1;
            }elseif(strtolower($a[$i]) > strtolower($b[$i])){
                return +1;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }

        }

    }
   static  function alphaorder($a,$b){
        $a = preg_replace('/\s+/','',trim($a));
        $b = preg_replace('/\s+/','',trim($b));
        $length= (count($a) < count($b)) ?  count($a) :count($b);
        for($i=0;$i<=$length;$i++){
            if(strtolower($a[$i]) > strtolower($b[$i])){
                return 1;
            }elseif(strtolower($a[$i]) < strtolower($b[$i])){
                return -1;
            }


        }
    }


   static  function comparator($a,$b){
        $a = preg_replace('/\s+/','',trim($a));
        $b = preg_replace('/\s+/','',trim($b));
        $return_value=0;
     if(($return_value=Alphabetizer::letterorder($a,$b))==0){
         if(($return_value=Alphabetizer::caseorder($a,$b) )== 0){
             if(($return_value=Alphabetizer::alphaorder($a,$b)) == 0){
               if(strlen($a) < strlen($b))  {
                 return 1;
               }else{
                   return 0;
               }
             }else{return$return_value;}
         }else{ return $return_value;}

     }else{
         return $return_value;
     }

    }


    public function transform(){
  usort($this->input,array(&$this,"Alphabetizer::comparator"));

    }
    public function output(){
        return array_unique($this->input);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

use php native function that is

`sort(array);` and here is a link for your help http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp

or if you want sorting alphabetically then use

`natcasesort(array)` and here is the link http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php

Comment: can this sort alphabetically as well as case? @agha-umair-ahmed

Comment: No It does not take care of case as you want

Comment: after sorting with netcasesort() i get this again this test
dallas University Texas
Dallas University Texas
Johnson Johnson
Johnson Johnson
test again this
test This
Texas dallas University
Texas Dallas University
This test
this test again
University Texas dallas
University Texas Dallas. the correct output should be this again this test
dallas University Texas
Dallas University Texas
Johnson Johnson
test again this
test This 
this test again 
Texas dallas University 
Texas Dallas University 
This test 
University Texas dallas 
University Texas Dallas @agha-umair-ahmed

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `natcasesort(array);`

I am getting this result for applying natcasesort on your array:

natcasesort gives following output:

```
 Array
 (
     [2] => again this test
     [8] => dallas University Texas
     [5] => Dallas University Texas
     [11] => Johnson Johnson
     [12] => Johnson Johnson
     [3] => test again this
     [0] => test This
     [9] => Texas dallas University
     [6] => Texas Dallas University
     [1] => This test
     [4] => this test again
     [10] => University Texas dallas
     [7] => University Texas Dallas
 )
```

natsort() gives following output:

```
 Array
 (
     [5] => Dallas University Texas
     [11] => Johnson Johnson
     [12] => Johnson Johnson
     [6] => Texas Dallas University
     [9] => Texas dallas University
     [1] => This test
     [7] => University Texas Dallas
     [10] => University Texas dallas
     [2] => again this test
     [8] => dallas University Texas
     [0] => test This
     [3] => test again this
     [4] => this test again
 )
```

Comment: this cannot sort all the values alphabetically @madforstrength

Comment: I have applied natcasesort on your array isnt it the result you want?

Comment: no . i want the index[4] to come before [9] because small case t should come before all T @madforstrength

Comment: the small case should come first

Comment: this is what i want  Array  (
     [2] => again this test
     [8] => dallas University Texas
     [5] => Dallas University Texas
     [11] => Johnson Johnson
     [12] => Johnson Johnson
     [3] => test again this
     [0] => test This
     [4] => this test again
     [9] => Texas dallas University
     [6] => Texas Dallas University
     [1] => This test     
     [10] => University Texas dallas
     [7] => University Texas Dallas
 )

Comment: It is not due to case, it is due to alphabetical order

Comment: it should consider the case first in this case after alphabetizing @madforstrength

Comment: This is exactly what it is doing, it is first sorting alphabetically so `th` can not come before `te`. Or if you want to do sorting with case first than alphabets that you can use `natsort`

Comment: i want th to come before Te because it has to consider the case of t  @madforstrength

Answer (score 0):

**Try this...**

```
     <?php
        $cars = array("test This", "This test", "again this test","test again this"
,"this test again","Dallas University Texas","Texas Dallas University","University Texas Dallas","dallas University Texas","Texas dallas University","University Texas dallas",
"Johnson Johnson","Johnson Johnson");
        arsort($cars);
        natcasesort($cars);
        print_r($cars);
        ?>
```

**Result:**

```
     Array ( [2] => again this test [8] => dallas University Texas 
[5] => Dallas University Texas [12] => Johnson Johnson [11] => Johnson Johnson 
[3] => test again this [0] => test This [6] => Texas Dallas University 
[9] => Texas dallas University [1] => This test [4] => this test again 
[7] => University Texas Dallas [10] => University Texas dallas )
```

**Reference Link:**
http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: this cannot sort all the values alphabetically correctly in order, it does well with case @deena

Comment: this is what i want   Array ( [2] => again this test [8] => dallas University Texas [5] => Dallas University Texas [11] => Johnson Johnson [12] => Johnson Johnson [3] => test again this [0] => test This [4] => this test again [9] => Texas dallas University [6] => Texas Dallas University [1] => This test [10] => University Texas dallas [7] => University Texas Dallas ) @deena

Comment: '  Array
 (
     [2] => again this test
     [8] => dallas University Texas
     [5] => Dallas University Texas
     [11] => Johnson Johnson
     [12] => Johnson Johnson
     [3] => test again this
     [0] => test This
     [4] => this test again
     [9] => Texas dallas University
     [6] => Texas Dallas University
     [1] => This test     
     [10] => University Texas dallas
     [7] => University Texas Dallas
 '@deena